# Can we use printwriter with Apache poi worksheet

Tags: java, excel, jakarta-ee, csv, apache-poi

I am creating a workbook and trying to download the same. The issue I am facing I am when I use the workbook.write(outputstream), it seems both outputstream and printwriter will not work together and this is creating an response already committed exception for me. Could you please let me know whether we have any ways to write this using printwriter, so I will come out of response already committed exception.

pRes.setContentType(MS_EXCEL);
            pRes.setHeader(CONTENT,FILENAME);

```
        outputStream = pRes.getOutputStream();
        workbook.write(outputStream);
```

The exception i am getting is,

java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:619)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:198)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flush(JspWriterImpl.java:173)

Comment: Any one have any idea on this?

Comment: Why are you creating the writer in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling from a jsp, you need to add this `<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>` to the page to stop the whitespaces from messing with your outputstream.

Comment: I am not calling from jsp, I am doing this inside a servlet and invoking servlet from jsp.

Comment: yeah, that's what I meant...  did you at least try it in the jsp?